# Accept only self signed SSL-Certificate C#

Tags: c#, https, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have a selfprogrammed API running on a Windows Server 2012 with a self signed SSL-Certificate. Now I want to communicate with the webservice via HTTPS.

The comunication is only at a local network, but i still want the conection to be secure.

Is there a way to accept only my self signed certificate? I found a lot of solutions to accept all certificates, but I only want mine to be accepted.

I already thought about adding it to the windows accepted certificates, but since the program consuming the webservice is user by serveral users on diffrent PC's and I do not have administration rights on all off them.

Is it even possible to have a secure connection the way I want it to be?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and is something you already have seen, use the same solution as to accept any certificate but validate it yourself inside the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` event.

Comment: ok this seems logical to me. do I check the hash sum of the certificate or what and how do I for my certificate?

Comment: This may help you: https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/06/11/https-and-x509-certificates-in-net-part-5-validating-certificates-in-code/

Comment: Why not add the certificate to your certificate store?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Gusman suggests, you should implement your own method for the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`. You can compare the thumbprint of the cert to validate whether it is the one you want to trust. Something like this should work:

```
public static class CertificateValidator
{
    public static string TrustedThumbprint { get; set; }

    public static bool ValidateSslCertificate(
        object sender,
        X509Certificate certificate,
        X509Chain chain,
        SslPolicyErrors errors)
    {
        // Wrap certificate to access thumbprint.
        var certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(certificate);

        // Only accept certificate with trusted thumbprint.
        if (certificate2.Thumbprint.Equals(
             TrustedThumbprint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // In all other cases, don't trust the certificate.
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your startup code, include the following to wire this up:

```
// Read your trusted thumbprint from some secure storage.
// Don't check it into source control! ;-)
CertificateValidator.TrustedThumbprint = SomeSecureConfig.Get["TrustedApiThumbprint"];

// Set the callback used to validate certificates.
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += CertificateValidator.ValidateSslCertificate;
```